# Execute Outlook VBA when sending email via MAPI from another software

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I use the following VBA code in **ThisOulookSession** to add BCC address when sending emails :

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objMe As Recipient
    Set objMe = Item.Recipients.Add("some@address.dot")
    objMe.Type = olBCC
    objMe.Resolve
    Set objMe = Nothing
End Sub
```

It works perfectly when sending from Outlook itself. But when I send emails via my CRM program using MAPI, the VBA is not executed. So I think sending emails using MAPI does not take **ThisOutlookSession** in account.

Is there a way to execute my VBA macro both with Outlook itself and via MAPI ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.ItemSend` event does not fire when a message is sent through Simple MAPI or a mailto link. This is by design.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information ! Is there a MAPI friendly way to add automatically a BCC ?

Comment: The best you can do is either specify BCC when sending the emails using Simple MAPI or create an Outlook addin that periodically scans the Application.Inspectors collection (since Application.Inspectors.NewInspector even does not fire either) and adds a BCC recipient appropriately.