# How to fire Outlook's Application_ItemSend when sending mail from an outside, non-Office, program?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want a macro to fire when I send emails. Right now it's just a msgbox:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim xText As String
    MsgBox ("hi there")
End Sub
```

This works when using Outlook itself but not when I send from, Nautilus LIMS, an outside program.

Comment: "when i send from an outside program" - it's not clear exactly what you mean by this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Outlook VBA when sending email via MAPI from another software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022769/execute-outlook-vba-when-sending-email-via-mapi-from-another-software)

Comment: [ItemSend event is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177345/itemsend-event-is-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Excel, make sure you have the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library checked. In the VBA IDE go to Tools/References, then scroll down to Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library, check the box and click OK. Also, make sure the Outlook program is running.
This code should work in an Excel VBA module.

```
Sub TestEmail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
               
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .display
        .To = "knappyflash2@gmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is a Test"
        .HTMLBody = "<FONT SIZE = 4><P>Hello,</P><P>This is a test Email</P><P>Thank you</P>" & .HTMLBody
        '.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying to help. This is a Nautilus LIMS program which uses outlook to send Emails. not another Office program